# Scripting via PuTTY or ....?

Tags: putty

Long ago I used a program called Procomm Plus in Windows for scripting/automating interactions with modems, etc.  Now I'm using PuTTY/ssh for similar things like dealing with Juniper Networks NetOS devices.  Right now I'm pretty much stuck with pasting text which doesn't allow looping.
I can think of a couple of variations on this:
- use something other than PuTTY ... but what?
- launch a script through PuTTY ... but how?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
-m, which will "read a remote command or script from a file"
```

Take a look at the [Putty Documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7) - Section 3.7 in particular.

Edit:

I remember now - I was using `plink` for this:

```
plink user@machine -m local_script.sh
```

plink is included with Putty.

Comment: It's not clear to me in reading the references how this would allow scripts with conditional branching. Just running a sequence of straight commands is easy enough - one can just copy and "paste" them. And, I see an option for adding a file which would be more automated than this manual method but either way I suspect it only works for in-line commands. Or don't I get it yet?  Oh yes, the name of the language used in Procomm Plus was Aspect.

Comment: @fred3 the script you call can have all sorts of logic within, including conditional branching.  So you'd only invoke one script at a time, but within that script you could utilize all the scripting functionality available on the remote machine (*nix I'd guess?)